# Is there any logging component for windows phone 8.1 silverlight?

Tags: win-phone-silverlight-8.1

what's the best way of logging error for wp 8.1 silverlight application? 
Neither log4net nor Nlog works on windows phone silverlight.
Any one have the same issue? Please throw me light.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.diagnostics.aspx) provides classes for logging messages and tracing events.

Comment: I can see from the debugger that there is a etl file generated with FileLoggingSession and LoggingChannel. And the file path+name is "C:\\Data\\Users\\DefApps\\APPDATA\\Local\\Packages\\b0c91f76-f3f9-4ccf-96fd-0e7f092ba0fd_831fjxmhge73e\\LocalState\\Logs\\Log-MySession-0.etl"
How can I copy out this file and see whether the logging information  is written into this file?